# Why is the method of im2col with GEMM is more efficient than the method of direction implementation with SIMD in CNN

Tags: computer-architecture, neural-networks, floating-point, memory-access

The convolutional layers are most computationally intense parts of Convolutional neural networks (CNNs).Currently the common approach to impement
convolutional layers is to expand the image into a column matrix(im2col) and perform and perform Multiple Channel Multiple Kernel (MCMK) convolution 
using an existing parallel General Matrix Multiplication (GEMM) library. However im2col operation need load and store the image data, and also need
another memory block to hold the intermediate data.

If I need to optimize the convolutional implementation, I may choose to direct implementation with SIMD instructions. Such method will not incur any
memory operation overhead.

***the benefits from the very regular patterns of memory access outweigh the wasteful storage costs.***

From the following link, at the end of the link

https://petewarden.com/2015/04/20/why-gemm-is-at-the-heart-of-deep-learning/

So I hope to know the reason. May floating point operations require more instruction cycle? or the input image is not much large, so it may residue
in the cache and the memory operations don't need access DDR and consume less cycles.

Comment: This rather low-level question might be more appropriate for stackoverflow or [scicomp.se], but could also fit here.